# jQuery, Clone select, disable previously selected options

Tags: jquery, select, clone, selecteditem

I'm working on this website where users can create their own bundles. Basically they have a list of courses and they can pick 5 and create a bundle.

The approach I'm taking is a dropdown list of all courses that then gets cloned on click.

What I'd like to do is disable any previously selected items on the next cloned list.

Is this possible?

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fLM/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one as well

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fLM/3/

As with your question it seems may be this could be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi PRP. Sorry I can't see any difference from the one I posted? :S

Comment: Opps forget to update jsfiddle with my script.. so you saw the same one that you posted.. my bad.. now I have updated the link.. so you should be able to see the changes..

Comment: That's a nice approach and I'm going for it :) Thanks a million! I had to fix a small problem which was caused when removing a cloned item: the previous dropdown was still disabled. Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kEKFX/

Comment: Awesome. I am glad my post was useful for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to work on somewhat similar requirement to your's but , instead of dynamically creating the select's I have 3 of them on the page.

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/a3yrQ/) .. It might be of help.

Comment: Wow this is a very nice piece of code. I think I'm gonna go with the other answer as it adapts to my code :) Thanks a million though, I'll keep this for future things to come ;)

Comment: @elmediano .. Sure not a problem :)

Comment: But in the Other fiddle I see that after all the selections are made.. If you go back to the 4th select , You can still see a selected option.. Point me If I am wrong

Comment: Sushanth you are totally right. The selected item should be removed from the previous and following selects. Mmmm seems I might end up using your code and accept your answer. I'll have a look :)

Comment: Because you are saying that the other answer is close to your requirement right.. So if possible try to tweak that .. If no other option try using mine

Comment: Well to be honest the other answer is an addition to my code so I thought it was a quicker way. But having thought about it, if I went with that answer I'd have to add some extra logic so if an option is selected, and then the user goes back and changes it, the rest of the selects would have to change too. Your answer actually does this by storing the values in an array... I think I'll probably come back to it tomorrow with a fresh pair of eyes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/VLrpn/

The key code comes right before attaching the new element:

```
$('.hidden-itemname').each(function(index) {
       newElem.children('.hidden-itemname').children('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove()
    });
```

Comment: You can actually disable the options by using:  
.attr('disabled', 'disabled').  
If you do so, you should set your first option (Please Select) to selected so that disabled items aren't selected by default

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. Having thought about it, I think .remove() makes more sense. Disabled might confuse the user, while if the item isn't there, they know those are the only options they have! Thanks!

Comment: Susanth made a good point below: "But in the Other fiddle I see that after all the selections are made.. If you go back to the 4th select , You can still see a selected option.. Point me If I am wrong". You can go back to a previous select and end up with duplicates. Might just disabled all previous selects... but the user would then have to remove elements in order to change his mind! Argh! Confusion! :P