# Jquery: Default value with disabling previously selected dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I found this jfiddle from another Stack post. It works fine except I'm looking to set the default value on the dropdown on load.

Instead of showing "-- Select --" for all 3 dropdown, I'm looking to load the values from a DB, hence it will display an existing value.

Of course this won't work.

```
<select id="select1"><option value="2">Question2</option></select><br />
<select id="select2"></select><br />
<select id="select3"></select></br>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/a3yrQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.val()` and trigger the change event.

`$('#select1').val(your value).change()`

```
$('#select1').val(1).change();
$('#select2').val(3).change();
$('#select3').val(4).change();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3yrQ/6/)**

Comment: Look's like it was my fiddle :D

Comment: Interesting, it's actually his jsfiddle from this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730841/jquery-clone-select-disable-previously-selected-options

Comment: Where would I put that line. I'll be the first to admit, I'm NOT a jquery guy. I threw that line after `var arrSelect` and it does show the default value BUT the value also appears in the other 2 dropdowns.

Comment: @luckytaxi.. Glad to have helped :)